# Indexing on date in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Document-

```
{
"name":"Add to Cart",
"creationTime":ISODate("2018-08-08T12:00:00Z")
},
{
"name":"Add to Cart",
"creationTime":ISODate("2018-08-08T12:01:00Z")
 },
 {
 "name":"Item Viewed",
 "creationTime":ISODate("2018-08-08T12:02:00Z")
 },
 {
 "name":"Item Viewed",
 "creationTime":ISODate("2018-08-08T12:03:00Z")
 },
 {
 "name":"Add to Cart",
 "creationTime":ISODate("2018-08-08T12:04:00Z")
 }
```

I create compound index on name and creationTime.

Query

```
   db.collection.find({$nor:[{"name":"Add to Cart"}]}).explain("executionStats");
```

scan only two doc  thats correct

Query-

```
   db.collection.find({$nor:[{"name":"Add to Cart"},{
    "creationTime":{$lt:new ISODate("2018-08-          
     08T12:03:00Z")}}]}).explain("executionStats");
```

scan all 5 doc.

why creationTime indexing not working.Is it due to timestamp in date.

Comment: There is a syntax Error in your query. `db.collection.find({$nor:[{"name":"Add to Cart"}, { "creationTime":{$lt: new ISODate("2018-08-08T12:03:00Z")}}]})`

Comment: Sorry for that but still its not taking advantage of indexing on creationTime